# Is there any way to detect if a database table exists with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to be able to create a table using

```
Schema::create('mytable',function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
});
```

But before that I would like to check if the table already exists, perhaps something like

```
Schema::exists('mytable');
```

However, the above function does not exist.  What else can I use?

Comment: Could you tell to what file you added this code ?

Answer (score 308, accepted):

If you are using Laravel 4 or 5 then there is the `hasTable()` method, you can find it [in the L4 source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php#L41) or the [L5 docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#checking-existence):

```
Schema::hasTable('mytable');
```

Comment: `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' does not have a method 'hasTable'`, I used `DB::hasTable('test')`because Schema class not found.

Comment: try DB::connection('xxxx')->getSchemaBuilder()->hasTable('xxx')

Comment: i try this and it's working... `DB::getSchemaBuilder()->hasTable('table_name_without_prefix')`

Comment: Schema::connection("bio_db")->hasTable('deviceLogs_11_2019')

Comment: @ShakeelAhmed table and view information are stored separately in the schema. You can query the schema yourself as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57959796/1269513

Comment: @PhillSparks Thanks for your suggestion, But I don't want to use Raw Query because it will not work if Database engine is changed..  I was looking if Eloquent provides some method like hasTable(). but no success.

Comment: What is the **namespace** of `Schema` ?

Comment: @AbelCallejo it is `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema`

Answer (score 33):

To create a new table there is only one check by Laravel Schema function `hasTable`.

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('table_name')) {
    // Code to create table
}
```

But if you want to drop any table before checking its existence then Schema have a function called `dropIfExists`.

```
Schema::dropIfExists('table_name');
```

It will drop the table if table will exist.

Answer (score 11):

As Phill Sparks answered, you can check whether a table exists using:

```
Schema::hasTable('mytable')
```

Notice that there are cases your app uses different connections. In this case, you should use:

```
Schema::connection('myConnection')->hasTable('mytable')
```

(Don't forget to use `use Schema;` on the beginning of your code).

Answer (score 5):

**if you are using different connection then you have to go with my answer.**

```
Schema::connection("bio_db")->hasTable('deviceLogs_11_2019')
```

here on `hasTable()` function you can pass more than 1 table name.

Answer (score 4):

No built in function for this in L3.  You can do a raw query:

```
$table = "foo";
$check = DB::only('SELECT COUNT(*) as `exists`
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_name IN (?)
    AND table_schema = database()',$table);
if(!$check) // No table found, safe to create it.
{
    // Schema::create …
}
```

Comment: Thanks!.. I'm using Laravel 3.

Comment: This is not fully cross-compatible across database types. For instance, it doesn't work with Sqlite or Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Rather, depend on information schema query instead of checking for some data in the tables with `COUNT()`.

```
SELECT table_schema 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = DATABASE()
      AND table_name = 'table_name';
```

Change your `'table_name'` value.

If you get one row output, it means the table exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('table_name')) {
 enter code here
}
```

Still working on Laravel 10