# Schema Builder : Create Table if not exists

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am using below code in Schema Builder to create table.

```
Schema::create('tblCategory', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('CategoryID');
    $table->string('Category', 40);
    $table->unique('Category', 'tblCategory_UK_Category');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Here is the problem is, if I have to create the new table, all old scripts runs and show error that table already exists.

is there any way to create table if not exists using Schema builder ?

Comment: Are you even using laravels built-in migration tool?

Comment: yes, 5.2.15 version.

Comment: And you run `php artisan migrate` ? If the file was run successfully, it should store that in the database so it won't run the file again

Comment: I am using `php artisan migrate:refresh` and next time, it tries to rerun the old scripts.

Comment: Try without `:refresh`

Comment: same issue when i ran this: `php artisan migrate`

Comment: No errors? (except trying to create a table that already exists) Is your migration table populated with the filenames of which it tries to run? If you try it on a new database, will it succeed without any errors, and therefore populate the migrations table with successfull migrated files?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Try this for create table if doesn't exist

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

if (!Schema::hasTable('tblCategory')) {
     Schema::create('tblCategory', function($table){
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('CategoryID');
            $table->string('Category', 40);
            $table->unique('Category', 'tblCategory_UK_Category');
            $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: You can also do `if (Schema::hasTable('tblCategory')) { return; }` before adding it instead.

Comment: hi is this line of code if (!Schema::hasTable('tblCategory')) {
     // create the tblCategory table
}
if table exists? correct?

Answer (score 6):

[Please check the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935990/is-there-any-way-to-detect-if-a-database-table-exists-with-laravel/43751840#43751840)

To create a new table there is only one check by Laravel Schema function `hasTable`.

But if you want to drop any table before checking its existence then Schema have a function called `dropIfExists`.

```
Schema::dropIfExists('table_name');
```

It will drop the table if table will exist.

Comment: Be careful while using this, it'll delete your existing table along with data.

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::transaction(function () {
        // Create your table here with schema builder.
});
```

If an exception is thrown within the transaction Closure, the transaction will automatically be rolled back. So trying to create a table already existing will throw an error. Most database transactions should have this closure in Laravel.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database