# Laravel: Checking Schema has database view?

Tags: php, laravel

How do i check, when `php artisan migrate` is working, has database view?

Something like this,

```
if(Schema::hasView('search_content')) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Try checking with hasTable only.

Comment: By using DB::statement("SHOW FULL TABLES IN database_name WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW';"); something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

`\DB::select("SELECT * FROM information_schema.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_NAME='table_name'")`

Answer (score 0):

It may not apply to everyone's needs buy I found myself into a similar problem after upgrading from Laravel 5.6 to 6.

I had a Mysql VIEW migration that needed to updated.

I'd also rather have a hasView() but instead of using hasTable() I am updating the full Mysql View statement using MySql CREATE **OR REPLACE** VIEW so that the view get overriden anyway.

```
CREATE or REPLACE VIEW full statement...
```